# Will this modified partitioning algorithm in quicksort function the same as the original in all situations?

Tags: c, algorithm, pivot, quicksort, partitioning

The code given in class for QuickSort partitioning procedure had two inner loops with an
empty body. Suppose we rewrite these loops by moving the increment/decrement from the
test into the body of the loop, and by modifying the initial values of the indexes accordingly.
The original and modified partitioning procedures are as follows:

```
int partition( A[], int l, int r )
{
    int pivot = A[l];
    int i = l, j = r+1;

    while(i < j)
    {
        while (A[--j] > pivot);
        while (A[++i] < pivot);
        if (i < j) swap (A[i], A[j]);
    }
    swap(A[l], A[j]);
    return j;
}

int partition( A[], int l, int r )
{
    int pivot = A[l];
    int i = l+1, j = r;

    while (i < j)
    {
         while (A[j] > pivot) j--;
         while (A[i] < pivot) i++;
         if (i < j) swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
    swap(A[l], A[j])
    return j;
}
```

Does the modified partitioning procedure work correctly in all situations? (ignore the
glitch of i running off the array when the pivot is the maximal element). Hint: consider what
happens when the current subarray contains at least two other keys equal to the pivot.

Comment: Yes that is supposed to say `A[i] < pivot`, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok well you were given a hint.  I suggest you trace through the code and see what happens with the example in the hint.  I'll give you a hint: something bad happens, but I won't tell you what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modified partitioning procedure gets into an infinite loop when the subarray contains at least two other values that are equal to the pivot.

Let's consider a case where we have:

```c
    int A[] = { 3, 3, 1, 3 };
```

And we call:

```c
    partition(A, 0, 3);
```

On the first iteration of the outer `while` loop, `i` is 1 and `j` is 3:

```c
3 3 1 3
  ^   ^  
  i   j
```

Consider the first test:

```c
         while (A[j] > pivot) j--;
```

It is not true that 3 is greater than 3, so `j` doesn't get decremented.

Now the second test:

```c
         while (A[i] < pivot) i++;
```

Similarly, it is not true that 3 is less than 3, so `i` doesn't get incremented.

When `A[i]` is swapped with `A[j]`, the array doesn't change because the values at `i` and `j` are the same.

The loop starts a new iteration because `i` is still less than `j`. Because nothing has changed since the previous iteration, the loop will go through the same tests and do the same thing, which amounts to nothing. Thus the infinite loop.